# compare the character in 2 strings taking into account the position

Tags: python, string

I am coding for a game similar to wordle
I need to compare 2 strings

- If the character and position is the same to return `-`
- If the character in `guess` is in the `answer` but wrong position to return `*`
- If character completely not in `answer` to return `.`

If my answer has 2 similar characters (eg, `guess`: accept, `answer`: castle), `*` can only be returned once, meaning the expected output would be `**.*.*`

I can't seem to iterate the string taking into account the position as well

```
def process(guess: str, answer: str) -> str:
    output = ""
    for i,ch in enumerate(guess):
        if ch not in answer:
            output += '.'
        elif ch != answer[i]:
            output += '*'
        else:
            output += '-'
    return output
```

Comment: are `guess` and `answer` the same length?

Comment: Count the letters in the input, and use a counter for the number of times a letter appears in the answer, keep subtracting that letter's counter until it becomes 0

Comment: guess and answer are the same length

Comment: Can you confirm for `answer = slosh` and `guess = pesos`, what is your expected output? Do you want `..**.` or `..***` ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't track the characters that you already identified in the `answer`, you can add a tracker string  to check for identified characters:

```py
def process(guess: str, answer: str) -> str:
    output = ""
    already_identified_characters = set()
    for i, ch in enumerate(guess):
        if ch not in answer or ch in already_identified_characters:
            output += "."
        elif ch != answer[i]:
            output += "*"
        else:
            output += "-"
        already_identified_characters.add(ch)
    return output
```

Comment: This gives the wrong output for `process('pesos','slosh')`, Expected is `..***`, your output is `..**.`. If OP wants Wordle like output, this is wrong.

Comment: Actually according to the OP the expected output is `..**.`, so I assume my logic works as requested.

Comment: That's not true, since they haven't mentioned a use case where the output itself has repeated characters. Assuming they are creating a Wordle checker, Wordle uses the same logic as my code. You may try it out here: https://mywordle.strivemath.com/?word=ozfvs. Try entering `pesos`, the right answer is `slosh`

Comment: Quoting from the OP: **If my answer has 2 similar characters (eg, guess: accept, answer: castle), `*` can only be returned once, meaning the expected output would be `**.*.*`**

Comment: You're right @Szabolcs but if you look carefully, his answer in that case has no repeated characters. If he were to provide a proper example that used repeated characters and what the expected output would be then the answer would change. From a data structure POV as well your solution is much more efficient, however it doesn't work like Wordle, which the OP also said: **I am coding for a game similar to wordle I need to compare 2 strings**.

Comment: @Abhigyan the emphasis is on **similar** which doesn't mean **same** according to the dictionary. Also based on the provided example the OP referred to the answer as his guess not to the variable called `answer`. So I think there is no need to nitpick on things anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If `guess` and `answer` are of equal length, this is how you could implement it:

```py
def process(guess: str, answer: str) -> str:
    output = []
    misplaced_chars = set()
    for g,a in zip(guess,answer):
        if g == a:
            # Identical character on same location
            output.append('-')
        elif g in answer and g not in misplaced_chars:
            # Character exists in answer
            output.append('*')
            misplaced_chars.add(g)
        else:
            # Wrong guess
            output.append('.')
     return ''.join(output)
```

Comment: It is possible that a letter repeats in the `answer`, in that case using set won't help.

Comment: The OP stated "* can only be returned once", which is why I'm using the set. Can you show me an example where the output is wrong? The set keeps a list of misplaced chars that have already had `*` returned, thereby falling back to `.`.

Comment: Hold on, let me try it myself. Meanwhile you can check my updated answer with some inputs to check if they give the same outputs as I got.

Comment: Ok so for the input `process("pesos","slosh")`, the expected output would be `'..***'` since that's what Wordle gives. OP wanted * to be returned once for the number of times the letter appears, like Wordle. Your output is `'..**.'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter` to keep track of the letters used in the answer, you can make sure that if letters are repeated in `answer`, they will work properly as well.

Basically, you keep track of each letter's count in the input, and subtract from it as you encounter matches.

```py
from collections import Counter
def process(guess: str, answer: str) -> str:
    countAnswer = Counter(answer)
    output = ""
    for i,ch in enumerate(guess):
        if ch not in answer:
            output += '.'
        elif countAnswer[ch]==0:
            output += '.'
        elif ch != answer[i] and countAnswer[ch]!=0:
            output += '*'
            countAnswer[ch]-=1
        else:
            output += '-'
    return output
```

This should work out very similar to Wordle's treatment of repeated characters.

Various Inputs and their Outputs:

```
>>> process("crate","watch")
'*.**.'

>>> process("crate","slosh")
'.....'

>>> process("pious","slosh")
'..-.*'

>>> process("pesos","slosh")
'..***'
```